# How to fix bottom margin to 2.5 cm and keep the page numbering in the middle

Tags: margins

I write my thesis using latex, and I have a problem with fixing the bottom margin with 2.5 cm including the page numbering in the middle of the distance of 2.5 cm as in the figure below

I use this command

```
\usepackage[left=3.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,includefoot,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
```

and I add this

```
\setlength{\footskip}{1.0cm}
```

[image: gin]

The resulting margin in the pdf file is not correct 
any suggestions ??

Comment: Please tell us more about your document setup. E.g., which document class do you employ? And, is either `\flushbottom` or `\raggedbottom` in effect?

Comment: Add `[footskip=1.25cm]` to the geometry options and probably remove `includefoot`.

Comment: The [includefoot] option redefines the bottom to include the footer.  Removing it uses the bottom as the bottom of the text area.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly intended as a demonstation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=3.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
Default footskip = \the\footskip

Bottom of text area = \the\dimexpr \paperheight-1in-\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep-\textheight\relax

2.5cm = \the\dimexpr 2.5cm\relax

\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```